# How to write multiple number of SQL queries from a single statement in node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Suppose I have Multiple number of create statements queries:

1.
var first="Create Table First...."

2.
var Second= "Create Table Second..."

...

I've tried maintaining every thing in a string array,
Like var Queries=[First,Second,...];
and then for looping and executing each statement.But what if I have to add a .then() after the last query is processed.

I'm wondering What's the correct approach on such situation?

PS: Sorry for the poor formatting,I'm new at this site.

Comment: I think a code sample might go a long way! In general though, executing mysql statements in sequence should work fine. What problems are you encountering?

Comment: Yeah the thing is first create statement should always come first as the other table are referencing it ,so if I try typing everything sequentially ,Due to the asynchronous nature of node.js the second create statements can run before the first.

Comment: sounds like a job for a promise library

Comment: Can you show me how will you do that with promise ?